# Scrolling upwards with a chat

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, containers, chat

I am building a chat app, however when a chat is added at the bottom of the messages container and there is an overflow,
even with `overflow-y: scroll`, the container does not scroll.

My message item css:

```css
.message-container{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: fit-content;
    padding: 2px 0;
}
```

The messages container css:

```css
.messages-body{
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Is there a way for this to work?

Comment: You still have to scroll the element yourself via code

Comment: How do I do this? I've tried adding an `onscroll` function, but this never gets called as it doesn't scroll in the first place.

Comment: You could set the scroll "y" of the container to some arbitrarily large number. Or  you could calculate the height of the inner element within the container, then set "y" to that. Possibly there will be no need to factor in the height of the visible view; but you could do so for completeness.